# Access and modify parameter from another class

Tags: flutter

I'm starting in flutter development by trying to build a simple ToDo app from scratch, not based on any tutorials, so I can learn better, but now I'm having trouble accessing the todos array from the equivalent widget...

to get things organized i have the structure:

```
lib
  pages
    home.page.dart
  widgets
    todo-card.dart
    todo-empty.dart
  main.dart
```

the app is a list of cards for each todo and a FAB for creating a new one. Each card is a delete button, part of the todo's text and a check button. All of the todos items are stored in the HomePage class:

**pages/home.page.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List todos = [
    {'text': 'texto teste 1', 'checked': false},
    {'text': 'texto teste 2', 'checked': true},
    {'text': 'texto teste 3', 'checked': false},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: this.todos.length > 0
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: this.todos.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map item = this.todos[index];

                return TodoCard(item['text'], item['checked']);
              },
            )
          : TodoEmpty(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the card structure:
**widgets/todo-card.dart**

```
class TodoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  bool checked = false;

  TodoCard(this.text, [this.checked = false]);

  @override
  _TodoCardState createState() => _TodoCardState();
}

class _TodoCardState extends State<TodoCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {

              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                widget.text,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: widget.checked
                  ? Icon(Icons.check_box)
                  : Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (widget.checked == true) {
                    widget.checked = false;
                  } else {
                    widget.checked = true;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my question is: **how can I access and delete `HomePage` properties from `TodoCard` class, so I can delete the index from the `todos` List?**

For now I don't want to use bloc, provider or other similar tools. Since I'm getting started with Flutter I'd like to master `setState()` first.

[Project repository on Github](https://github.com/gabrielcesar95/todo)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a Function as parameter to the TodoCard class like this

```
class TodoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  bool checked = false;
  Function onTodoCardDeleted;

  TodoCard(this.text, this.onTodoCardDeleted, [this.checked = false]);

  @override
  _TodoCardState createState() => _TodoCardState();
}
```

And in the HomePage you would create the TodoCard object like this

```
/* your code */
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  Map item = this.todos[index];
  return TodoCard(item['text'], (){ _removeFromTodos(index); }, item['checked']);
},
/* your code */

_removeFromTodos(int index){
  setState((){
    todos.removeAt(index);
  });
}
```

In the end you can call the function passed as parameter on the delete icon tap

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
  onPressed: () {
    widget.onTodoCardDeleted;
  },
),
```

Comment: that worked! Thanks a lot!

the only thing I had to change was: `widget.onTodoCardDeleted;` to: `widget.onTodoCardDeleted();`